# Inequality involving the distances from a fixed point in triangle to triangle sides and vertices

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, geometric-inequalities

Let $P$ be a point of an acute-angled triangle $ABC$, and $K,L,M$ be the projections of $P$ onto $BC,CA,AB$ respectively. Prove that $PK\cdot PL\cdot PM\le\frac{1}{8}\cdot PA\cdot PB\cdot PC$.

Comment: try prove $PA+PB+PC\geqslant (PL+PM)(PM+PK)(PK+PL)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll prove that 
$$BC\cdot PA\geq AB\cdot PM+AC\cdot PL.$$
Indeed, let $CF$ is an altitude of $\Delta APC$ and $BG$ is an altitude of $\Delta APB.$

Thus, $$BC\cdot PA\geq(BG+CF)PA=2S_{\Delta APB}+2S_{\Delta APC}=AB\cdot PM+AC\cdot PL.$$
By the same we we can obtain:
$$AC\cdot PB\geq AB\cdot PM+BC\cdot PK$$ and
$$AB\cdot PC\geq  BC\cdot PK+AC\cdot PL.$$
Thus, by AM-GM we obtain:
$$AB\cdot AC\cdot BC\cdot PA\cdot PB\cdot PC\geq$$
$$\geq\left(BC\cdot PK+AC\cdot PL\right)\left( AB\cdot PM+BC\cdot PK\right)\left(AB\cdot PM+AC\cdot PL\right)\geq$$
$$\geq8\sqrt{AB^2AC^2 BC^2PK^2PL^2PM^2}=8AB\cdot AC\cdot BC\cdot PK\cdot PL\cdot PM$$
and we are done!

Comment: amazing solution! (+1)

Comment: yes indeed it is

Comment: your inequality equivalent to $(AP+PK)\cdot BC\ge 2S$, which is true since $AP+PK\ge AK\ge h_{BC}$, right?

Comment: @tong_nor I fixed my post. See now please.

Comment: very nice solution, thanks!

Comment: @tong_nor Welcome!