# Sum of distances from interior point to vertices is greater than double the sum of distances to edges

Tags: geometry, geometric-inequalities

Let $\triangle ABC$, $M\in Int(\triangle ABC)$. Let $MD\perp BC$, $ME\perp AC$ and $MF\perp AB$, $D\in BC$, $E\in AC$, $F\in AB$. Prove that
$$MA+MB+MC\geq 2\cdot(MD+ME+MF).$$

My only idea is to use the fact that $MA+MD>AD$ and the similars and I would need to prove that
$$AD+BE+CF\geq 3\cdot (MD+ME+MF)$$
but I did not manage to do that.

Comment: This is [Erdős–Mordell inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Mordell_inequality).

Comment: @ACB Interesting. I didn't know it. Two remarks 1) This inequality is said indeed in your reference a consequence of Barrow's inequality 2) A surprizing (cousin ?) multiplicative inequality is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2334633)

Comment: @JeanMarie ... Do you remember [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4345045/geometric-inequality-with-variable-point-in-a-triangle-and-circumcircles-radii#comment9065596_4345045)? (surprizing!)

Comment: @ACB Though a recent question, I hadn't memorized it (coming Alzheimer ?). Thank you very much for sharing. This is a very good aspect of SE site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use [Barrow's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrow%27s_inequality). with notations mixing yours and those of this Wikipedia article:

$$MA+MB+MC \ge 2(MU+MV+MW) \ge 2(MD+ME+MF)$$

because the altitudes lengths, in each triangle $MAB$, $MBC$, $MCA$ is shorter than the angle bissector lengths.

The case of equality is clearly when $ABC$ is equilateral.